# How to set up (quickly and easily) an HTTPS server for development/debugging?

Tags: https, http, website

I cannot seem to find an easy solution to this or one that does not involve buying software.

It's simple, I have an HTTP website that I am developing, I need to debug its behavior under HTTPS (because some things are disabled on insecure origins).

I just need a simple way to set up an HTTPS site that redirects all requests to it to my current HTTP site.

Something like a tunnel from https://example.com => http://example.com

Could someone provide **simple**, **step by step**, and **working** instructions on how to achieve this?

Edit: What I want could be something like `ngrok` but local and free.

Comment: You don't redirect https to http, you just get your certs, put the website on https, and then redirect http to https.

Comment: Yeah, also by tunnel I was not talking about making a hole through a mountain ... I'm pretty sure you know what I mean, Michael.

Comment: You could put HaProxy in front of your webserver, and let it do the https offloading. The "simple, step by step, and working instructions" can be found on the internet.  BTW, if you don't follow Michael's advice, I wish you good luck.